# Getting call back to function within nested html tag

Tags: jquery, callback, this, image

I have a callback, which I've had help on previously, which gets the last slide visible on a jCarousel.

The callback itself works, but its getting the list (which is the first tag), and I want it to get the `alt` attribute from the HTML. Is there anything I should be doing to delve deeper to grab the desired attribute?

I'm trying to get the `alt` attribute from the image tag and not the first list or anchor.

```
function itemVisibleIn(carousel) {
    $("#gallerydescription").html( $(this).attr("alt")); 
};

<li><a href="images/gallery/placeholder1.png" rel="shadowbox" title="This is the description">**<img class="caption" src="images/gallery/placeholder1.png" width="750" height="450" title="test Title1" alt="This is the title" />**</a></li>
```

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what the `carousel` var returns?

Comment: sorry this a direct post from the manual

Comment: JavaScript function that is called (after the scroll animation) when an item becomes the first one in the visible range of the carousel. Four parameters are passed: The instance of the requesting carousel and the <li> object itself, the index which indicates the position of the item in the list and the state of the carousel action (prev, next or init). Alternatively, you can pass a hash of one or two functions which are triggered before and/or after animation:

itemFirstInCallback: {
  onBeforeAnimation: callback1,
  onAfterAnimation: callback2
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to use `find` to get that `img`.  Something like this:

```
$(this).find("img").attr("alt")
```

If needed, the selector passed to `find` can be more specific to distinguish between multiple images.  Possibly something like this, to just get the image with a class of caption:

```
$(this).find("img.caption").attr("alt")
```

Comment: hmm i still cant get it going, i think its what im doing via the callback. can you see anything from the comments above? is it possible im returning something incorrectly?

Comment: From the piece of the documentation that you posted it would seem that the `li` is the 2nd parameter passed to your callback and not `this`.

Comment: yeah, im really lost at the moment its really getting on top of me.

Comment: If you can create a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.com) with what you have now, I'll have a look.  Not particularly familiar with jcarousel.

Comment: i cant get anything goin in jfiddle

http://www.webphibian.com/standards/slideshows/jslideshow-test.php#4

that site has a jcarousel at the bottom and he is using it to get the tags for the photo name and the photographer, for the life of me i cant find out how to replicate it

Comment: Do you have a working copy somewhere that can be seen?  It's difficult to debug something without seeing it.  ALso, in the link you just posted he is using jcarousel as well as jquery cycle.  Are you using both of these?  And, the callback you posted, which event is this a callback for?

Comment: Yeah unfortunately i don't have a working copy to go off at the moment. thanks for all your help i know its hard to help if there's only a vague idea. 

The event i posted for was when the carousel changes, the image that becomes visible is the target. Im hoping for it to identify which line is visible and then for me to parse the "alt" tag of that image into another of my divs. 

I hope that make some type of sense.